# What is the expectation of the following joint CDF?

Tags: probability, expected-value, joint-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, copula

Yesterday, I asked the following question regarding copulas:

> "Let's say $X=(X_1,X_2)′$, where $X\in \mathbb R^2$. What is the expectation of the copula function $C(F_{X_1}(x_1),F_{X_2}(x_2))$ - i.e. $\mathbb E_X[C(F_{X_1}(x_1),F_{X_2}(x_2))]$?"

Here, I rephrase this question in a form familiar to most:

> Let's say $X=(X_1,X_2)′$, where $X\in \mathbb R^2$. What is the expectation of the joint CDF $F(F_{X_1}(x_1),F_{X_2}(x_2))$ - i.e. $\mathbb E_X[F(F_{X_1}(x_1),F_{X_2}(x_2))]$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be different to the previous question

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: the question changed by not mentioning copula functions, as the OP hypothesized that joint CDFs were more common knowledge to readers of CV than copula functions.

Comment: If it's asking about the same object (even while using a different terminology and presentation), it's the same question with answers to one serving as answers for the other. This is the main test for closure as a duplicate. (Though a possible small edit to the question would make the original more canonical by explicitly pointing out the equivalence). Since this one has an answer, I'll vote to close the other.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not well defined: it depends on the function $C$.

As an extreme example, suppose the copula function $C$ is one such that $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$. In such a case, the distribution of $C(F_{X_1}(X_1), F_{X_2}(X_2))$ is that of the product of two uniform(0,1) distributions. On the other extreme, suppose $X_1$ has a deterministic, monotonic relation with $X_2$. Then the distribution of  $C(F_{X_1}(X_1), F_{X_2}(X_2))$ is simply the distribution of a single uniform(0,1). The expected value of these two distributions are different, therefore the answer is not well defined without further restrictions on $C$.